# Regression analysis and least square method relation?

Tags: regression, data-analysis

I want to know where Regression analysis is most used at, what's its competitor methods, and how least square method relates to regression analysis.

Comment: Is this homework? If yes please show what you have so far and explain your difficulty.

Comment: No, it is not, and it doesn't seem like it either :) i just want to know how least square relates to regression analysis, and where does regression analysis stand as solution ? and to what problems (if possible with use cases)

Comment: Ok the question doesn't look like homework, but it also doesn't look very researched ;) It's always better to provide a bit of context, especially if the question is about general concepts which are defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know where Regression analysis is most used at

[Regression analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) is used for analyzing the relationship between some independent variables and a dependent variable. In particular it can be used for predicting/forecasting the dependent variable. In Machine Learning a regression task is a supervised task where the target (dependent variable) is numerical (as opposed to classification). It's used in a huge range of applications.

> what's its competitor methods

There's no competitor since it's a whole domain: any method which does the same thing is a regression method so it's part of regression analysis.

> how least square method relates to regression analysis.

[Least Squares Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) is a specific method which can be used in regression analysis. Its most common use is with linear regression, which is a specific case of regression for a linear function (it's one of the most simple forms of regression).